# Couldn't invoke EventHandler for AutoGeneratedColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, events, handler

I have a datagrid in my WPF application and i am binding an Ienumerable collection to the itemsource of the datagrid.

I need to add a handler for AutoGenerated columns in DataGrid after binding it.
But i can't.

```
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ineumerable_collection;
dataGrid1.AutoGeneratedColumns += new EventHandler(dataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns);//Not working
```

I have set Autogeneratecolumns as True in my XAML. But when i run my application it is not invoking the event handler dataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns.
Thanks in advance if u could solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're attaching the event handler after you've changed the `ItemsSource`, which means the columns get generated before your handler is attached. Just switch the order of the two statements.

```
dataGrid1.AutoGeneratedColumns += new EventHandler(dataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns);
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ineumerable_collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But when i run my application it is not invoking the event handler

You should *first* subscribe to the event:

```
dataGrid1.AutoGeneratedColumns += dataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns
```

and *then* change items source:

```
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ineumerable_collection;
```

because this event raised after `ItemsSource` changed and the last column was generated.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

> The AutoGeneratedColumns event is raised every time the DataGrid
>   attempts to generate columns.For example, AutoGeneratedColumns is
>   raised when the DataGrid is initialized, AutoGenerateColumns is set to
>   true, or the ItemsSource is changed, even if the ItemsSource is null.

Try to subscribe on an event before setting ItemsSource.